# Perl Imager - libpng PNG libraries or headers not found

Tags: macos, perl, libpng

I am trying to run Perl script in Terminal - the outcome should be image.png (picture of OID for "magical pen"), but I keep running error. Not being programmer I used all my googling skills for more than a month with no success.
I use MacBook - macOS Monterey.

- Installed Homebrew,
- used the brew install perl,
- than brew install libpng,
- in the perl -MCPAN -eshell tried to install Imager (and YAML and MP3::Info that is also needed) - that didn't show any errors.

I am certain that this should work (tried the same steps on an older MacBook and the script ran just fine).
During the installation on the other Mac there were no issues, on my Mac I had to do some changes for the Home-brew.
I am also not sure, if the Imager can use the libpng.
Well, don't ask me why, but I tried to install Imager::File::PNG and this is what I get:

Running install for module 'Imager::File::PNG' Checksum for    /Users/darina/.cpan/sources/authors/id/T/TO/TONYC/Imager-File-PNG-0.99.tar.gz    ok Scanning cache /Users/darina/.cpan/build for sizes    ............................................................................DONE  Configuring T/TO/TONYC/Imager-File-PNG-0.99.tar.gz with Makefile.PL   PNG: building independently PNG: Generic: includes not found -    libraries found PNG: v1.6: includes not found - libraries found PNG:    v1.5: includes not found - libraries not found PNG: v1.4: includes    not found - libraries not found PNG: v1.2: includes not found -    libraries not found PNG: v1.0: includes not found - libraries not    found PNG: base (+libz): includes not found - libraries not found    PNG: v1.6 (+libz): includes not found - libraries not found PNG: v1.5    (+libz): includes not found - libraries not found PNG: v1.4 (+libz):    includes not found - libraries not found PNG: v1.2 (+libz): includes    not found - libraries not found PNG: v1.0 (+libz): includes not found

- libraries not found PNG: Checking if the compiler can find them on its own PNG: Test code failed: Can't link/include 'png.h', 'stdio.h',    'png' OS unsupported: PNG libraries or headers not found Warning: No    success on command[/usr/local/Homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/bin/perl    Makefile.PL]   TONYC/Imager-File-PNG-0.99.tar.gz      /usr/local/Homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK    Failed during this command:  TONYC/Imager-File-PNG-0.99.tar.gz           : writemakefile NO '/usr/local/Homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/bin/perl    Makefile.PL' returned status 512

Can anyone help me please, preferably with very detailed instructions like for a child?
Thank you
Darina

Comment: I tested this on macOS Monterey 12.4. Homebrew version 3.5.9, perl version 5.34.0. I first reinstalled libpng, see log [here](https://pastebin.com/2CKbbiDq). Then ran command `cpan Imager::File::PNG`, which worked fine, see log [here](https://pastebin.com/CY4Cp3FF)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I reinstalled the libng via homebrew, I have much shorter log (first 11 lines). MacOS Monterey 12.5 and same perl version like you.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED! I finally made it work. Possibly not the best solution since I am mostly copying and pasting other people solution (this was not Perl or Imager related).

I installed pkg-config (again via brew install pkg-config), than used pkg-config --cflags libpng, which actually found the directory of the package and then it finally let me install the Imager::File::PNG - saying PNG: Found via pkg-config libpng.

For people, who actually know, what just happened, feel free to leave a comment, I definitely won't be offended.

Answer (score -1):

The error message has "PNG libraries or headers not found". This means that you need to install extra stuff. Package managers often have multiple packages for a library, such as the `libpng` and `libpng-dev`. The latter one includes the header files and other things that another library would need to use `libpng`.

Personally, I don't use `brew`. I download the source, compile it, and install it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am not sure, how to do that. Brew doesn't recognise the libpng-dev... so I used Rscript (found a topic here about similar issue so I was hoping it will solve the problem), but the error message is still the same. Any suggestion?